# GridToForm in free-jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have the next code:

```
    if (gsr) {
            $gridsalariati.jqGrid('GridToForm', gsr, "#form_salariat");
    }
```

In free-jqgrid 4.8.0 at line 11630 :

```
    $fieldi[propOrAttr]("checked", $fieldi.val() === String(rowdata[i]));
```

When run function: 'GridToForm' show this error:

```
    TypeError: $fieldi[propOrAttr] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, it's a bug. The definition of `propOrAttr` should be `propOrAttr = $t.p.propOrAttr;` instead of the typing error `propOrAttr = $t.p.useProp;`.

I've fixed the code of free jqGrid. You should refresh the sources from the [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).